# Resolution of the identity (basic questions)

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, banach-algebras

There are a few advanced discussions about the title:

1. [Resolution of Identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429921/resolution-of-identity)
2. [Resolution of Identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403744/resolution-of-identity)
3. [Resolution of identity of a selfadjoint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260217/resolution-of-identity-of-a-selfadjoint)

I just want to ask the most fundamental part of it. (I am not a student in math.)

From the definition in Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_functional_calculus

> Let $T$ be a self-adjoint operator. If $E$ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbf{1}_E$ is the indicator function, then $\mathbf{1}_E(T)$ is a **self-adjoint projection** on $H$. Then mapping $$\Omega: E\mapsto \mathbf{1}_E(T)$$ is a projection-valued measure called the **resolution of the identity** for the self-adjoint operator $T$ ($H$ is a Hilbert space).

1. I am still confused about how does $\mathbf{1}_E(T)$ really work. $E\subset\mathbb{R}$; however, $T$ is an operator defined on $H$. So $T\notin E$
2. How does $\mathbf{1}_E(T)$ act on vectors in $H$?
3. "resolution of the identity": where does "resolution" and "identity" come from this definition.

Could anyone please let me know these (much better if a concrete example provided)

Comment: $1_E(T)$ is defined using the Borel functional calculus, which is a tool that allows you to apply Borel functions like $1_E$ to self-adjoint operators like $T$. Roughly the idea is that you apply the desired function to the eigenvalues and leave the eigenvectors the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let me elaborate a bit more.

### Diagonal self-adjoint operators

Let $\mathsf{H}$ be a (separable) Hilbert space with an orthonormal basis $(e_n)$. Take a non-empty compact set $K \subset \mathbb{R}$ and a sequence $(\lambda_n)$ of distinct points from $K$ such that the closure of the set $\{ \lambda_n \colon n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is $K$.
We construct a self-adjoint operator on $\mathsf{H}$ with spectrum $\sigma(A)=K$ by setting
$$Ax = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\lambda_n \left<x, e_n\right>e_n$$
for all $x \in \mathsf{H}$.

The function $E \colon \mathcal{B}(K) \rightarrow B(\mathsf{H})$, where $\mathcal{B}(K)$ stands for the set of all bounded Borel function on $K$ and $B(\mathsf{H})$ is the space of linear bounded operators on $\mathsf{H}$, defined by
$$E(B)x = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \textbf{1}_{B}(\lambda_n) \left<x,e_n\right>e_n$$
is the resolution of identity (spectral measure, [link](http://planetmath.org/spectralmeasure)) for $A$ and it is often denoted by $\mathbf{1}_B(A):=E(B)$ (this notation is consistent with the application of functional calculus, discussed further in the answer) for all $B \in \mathcal{B}(K)$. Furthermore the following holds
$$(\star) \ \ \qquad  Ax = \int_{\sigma(A)} \lambda \  E(\mathrm{d}\lambda)x = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\lambda_n \left<x, e_n\right>e_n,$$
where $\int_{\sigma(A)} \lambda \  E(\mathrm{d}\lambda)$ is an integral with respect to the spectral measure $E$ of $A$ (I'm not going to define this integral here, check this [link](http://planetmath.org/spectralmeasure), $(\star)$ supposed to give the intuition).

### Notation

In Physics people often use the Dirac notation, that is, since the above $A$ can be written by $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \lambda_n \left|e_n\right>\left<e_n\right|$ or even $\sum_{i}  \lambda_i  \left|i\right> \left<i\right|$ (if we use the notation $(\left|i\right>)$ to denote the orthonormal basis) then the following notation can be often seen $$A = \int \lambda \ \mathrm{d}\left|i\right>\left<i\right|$$
for any self-adjoint operators (not-necessarily diagonal).

### General case

Now take an arbitrary self-adjoint operator on $\mathsf{H}$ (not-necessarily diagonal). The spectral theorem states that
$$A = \int_{\sigma(A)} \lambda \ E(\mathrm{d}\lambda),$$
where $E$ is the corresponding resolution of identity (spectral measure) for $A$.

In particular, one may want to consider the Borel functional calculus. Given a bounded borel function $f \in \mathcal{B}(\sigma(A))$ we have that
$$ f(A) = \int_{\sigma(A)} f(\lambda) \ E(\mathrm{d} \lambda).$$

### Name

The term identity in the name probably comes from the fact that
$$\mathbf{1}_{\sigma(A)}(A) = I_{\mathsf{H}},$$
and I think that resolution corresponds to the spectral form of the operator.

### Spectral theorem - different version

There is also a multiplication operator version of the spectral theorem which says that any self-adjoint operator is unitarily equivalent to the operator of multiplication on some space $L^2(\mu)$ for some measure $\mu$. Recall that a multiplication operator with symbol $f\in L^{\infty}(\mu)$ is $M_f \in B(L^2(\mu))$ given by $(M_f g)(x) = f(x)g(x)$. One may want to check [this link for further information](http://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/watkins/Math502/pdfiles/spectral.pdf).

In particular, the spectral measure for multiplication operator $M_f$ is given by $E(B) = \mathbf{1}_{f^{-1}(B)}$ for $B \in \mathcal{B}(\sigma(M_f))$.

Comment: In the undergraduate, we have learned $Ax = \lambda x = \lambda ( \sum \langle x,e_n\rangle e_n)$, just decomposing the vector $x$. What is the difference btw this and the first equation in your answer?

Comment: For an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ and the corresponding eigenvector $x$, you have $Ax = \lambda x$, and indeed Fourier series form of $ x = \sum_n \left<x, e_n\right>e_n$. Note that in the first equation in my answer you have $\lambda_n$ it depends on $n$ so you cannot take it out of the summation. Howeover,  by using equation $1$ you can get $Ae_k = \lambda_k e_k$ for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, in other words the vector $e_k$ corresponds to the eigenvalue $\lambda_k$. Is it clear now?

Comment: Just kindly make sure that in the integral if replacing $\sigma(A)$ by $B$, i.e., $\int_{B}\lambda \  E(\mathrm{d}x)x$, then it equals to  $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \textbf{1}_{B}(\lambda_n) \left<x,e_n\right>e_n$?

Comment: No, it does not. Note that $$\int_{\sigma(A)} \lambda E(d\lambda)x = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \lambda_n\left<x, e_n\right>e_n.$$ However, we have that $$E(B) = \int_B E(d\lambda) = \int_{\sigma(A) } \textbf{1}_B(\lambda) E(\mathrm{d}\lambda) = \sum_n  \textbf{1}_B(\lambda_n) \left<x, e_n\right>e_n.$$ This is only valid for the above diagonal self-adjoint operator $A$.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer.